# How to adjust the `seasonal` parameter of `statsmodel.tsa.seasonal.STL`?

Tags: python, statsmodels, forecasting

I'm using the StatsModel implementation of the STL decomposition (https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/generated/statsmodels.tsa.seasonal.STL.html). Does anyone have any advice on how to set the `seasonal` parameter of the function? My period is 168 and I have over 1600 points, so I don't think the default `7` is right in my case.

I have tried different values and the pattern change a lot.